# Bootup Asp.Net Application without using IIS Application Pool configuration StartMode = "AlwaysRunning"

Tags: asp.net, iis, startup

I have Asp.Net Web-Api Application which I have hosted on IIS 7.5. 
I want to do some task when application pool starts up(recycled) to which my application is pointed. I know there is **Application Initialization Module** available from IIS 7.5 onwards.
But for that I need to set application pool configuration => **startMode="AlwaysRunning"**.
This will keep application pool always running even when there is no request to be served for long time.
Is there any way by which on boot up of my application, I can perform initialization task without keeping application Pool always running ?